# no usage found in project files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-19

I am learning Java last some days in IntelliJ. Yesterday I updated JDK (Java 19.0.1, 2022-10-18) and deleted old IntelliJ and installed new IntelliJ. After I created a project and it shows no usage.

```
no usage
public class Main {
no usage
    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yizz1.png)
}
```

If I click on "no usage" then no usage found in project file and after on it then FIND USAGE BOX popup.

I am beginner. Please help me. What is it and how to resolve?

Comment: Seems you have Code vision hints enabled in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Intentions". They show if there are any class/method usages in other files. There are no in your case.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS63m.png)

Uncheck usages hint.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for the pointint out the exact settings, where i can turn it off. 
But it would be better to explain it in your answer instead of just giving a link to a picture. 
Your picture can become unavailable in the future, so your answer will become useless.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the no usage
and you’ll see options saying hide click on that